# Adding Quicklook to an existing NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've been searching high and low for an example of an easy implementation of Quicklook to an existing NSTableView and while I've found example projects they're way beyond my skill set to disassemble and duct-tape into my project.

I can get the Quicklook window to appear when a button is pressed using

```
[[QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanel] makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

But I haven't the slightest clue on how to set the data source so that the window is populated with the file.

Simply put, is there any stupid-simple tutorial on how to do this...?

Comment: Setting a datasource is as easy as `panel.dataSource = myDatasource`. Does the tableview have a datasource and a delegate?

Comment: The tableview is populated with the contents of an array that's built out of a sqlite db.  The tableview does have it's own delegate which handles the population.  One of the columns of the table is a path to the file that I want to quicklook...  I just can't figure out how to tell quicklook to use that...

Comment: Just implement the QLPreviewPanelDataSource methods

Answer (score 0):

**Create a class that conforms to the `QLPreviewItem` protocol and implement**:

```
- (NSURL *)previewItemURL {
    // <Return File URL for file you want to preview>
}
```

**Have your class that triggers the preview panel implement `QLPreviewPanelDataSource, QLPreviewPanelDelegate` and add the following to your implementation:**

```
# pragma mark - QuartzPanel

- (IBAction)togglePreviewPanel:(id)previewPanel {
    if ([QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanelExists] && [[QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanel] isVisible]) {
        [[QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanel] orderOut:nil];
    } else {
        [[QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanel] makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    }
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)acceptsPreviewPanelControl:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel {
    return YES;
}

- (void)beginPreviewPanelControl:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel {
    _previewPanel = panel; // create a property to hold a reference to your panel
    panel.delegate = self;
    panel.dataSource = self;
}

- (void)endPreviewPanelControl:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel {
    _previewPanel = nil;
}

#pragma mark - QLPreviewPanelDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewPanel:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel {
    return self.previewItems.count; // Items to preview of your custom subclass you created above
}

- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewPanel:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return (id<QLPreviewItem>)self.previewItems[index];
}


#pragma mark - QLPreviewPanelDelegate

- (BOOL)previewPanel:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel handleEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    // redirect all key down events to the table view
    if ([event type] == NSKeyDown) {
        NSString *key = [event charactersIgnoringModifiers];
        if ([key isEqual:@" "]) {
            [self togglePreviewPanel:self];
        }
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Which class should be "the class that triggers the preview panel"? The tableview, its delegate, its datasource, a controller, the button or something else? (I'm trying to understand and learn)

Comment: whichever class contains the IBAction mapped from your button you're pressing for quicklook